# How to fully undo an Insert Page Numbers operation in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

From the top ribbon menu I have chosen `Insert->Page number->Bottom of Page->Plain number 2` in my Word document.

Word added the page numbers but added headers and footers to my document, and also changed the color of the text from black to a fairly pale and hard-to-read gray.

I've chosen the `Page Number-Remove page number` option, and although the numbers are gone, the headers and footers are still there, and the color of the text is still gray.

"Undo" [CTRL-Z] has no effect.

`Header->Remove header` and `Footer->Remove footer` have no effect.

I can't even tell you what version I'm using. There is no `Help->About` that I can find in this `<insert expletive here>` ribbon.  I pay a monthly subscription for it and it runs on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Word uses the *footer* style when inserting page numbers. Insert the page numbers as you said in your question, then edit the *footer* style. Very likely there is the problem.